# UINavigationBar position is not the same depending on iOS version ( 7 and 6 )

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm updating my app to iOS7 and I noticed that I had to re-adjust all my manually placed `UINavigationBars` so that they come under the status bar.

Now that all bars have been manually moved in the `IB` below the status bar I've a problem that it looks great on iOS7 but in any other version there is a pronounced gap between the status bar and the `UINavigationBar`.

Could anyone advice me why is this problem happening between iOS versions and how to overcome it?

**iOS7**

[image]

**iOS6**

[image]

Comment: Check out the iOS 7 transition guide https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/index.html (Username and Password required) Your `UINavigationBar` should incorporate the `UIStatusBar` in iOS7 it should appear under it. So your `y` position will start at `0` and you will have to add the extra 20 pixels to the `UINavigationBars` height.

Comment: But it works great on iOS7, how does that refer to iOS6?

Comment: It doesn't appear correctly, in your iOS 7 image you are dropping the `UINavigationBar` below the `UIStatusBar` so your `y` position is starting at 20 pixels when it should be 0. Your `UIStatusBar` should be the same color as your `UINavigationBar` as it is transparent. The white you are seeing on the status bar is from the `UIView` behind your `UINavigationBar`. So because you are adding those extra 20 pixels to drop the `UINavigationBar` below the `UIStatusBar` it doing the same in the ios 6 version. Set the `y` position to 0.

Comment: On iOS6 the `y position` starts after the `UIStatusBar` whereas in iOS7 it starts at the same point as the `UIStatusBar`. Again your `UINavigationBar` is actually wrong on both iOS6 and iOS7.